# How to set event start and end time dynamically when allDay is set to false with fullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using a fullcalendar application where upon clicking on an event it opens a     modal with event information. In this modal, it is possible to change event data too, think of event.start, event.end, and event.allDay.

When the allDay checkbox is clicked, the event is automatically updated to represent the new state, however, when the event has been a non-allDay event before. The event data contains two extra properties: oldStart and oldEnd. These two properties I want to be used when the event.allDay is set to false; the event.start should then be set to oldStart and event.end should be set to oldEnd.

The problem is that with this method, when updating the start and end time of an event after setting event.allDay to false, the event when updated disappears from the calendar view and is being updated in the back-end to represent the start time as 00:00 and end time as the event start + defaultEventDuration (which in my case is 02:00:00).

My code looks like this:

```
function changeAllDay(id) { // Function to change allDay property of event that was clicked on

    // Find corresponding event
    var event = findEvent(id);

    event.allDay = !event.allDay; // Change allDay value

    // Set start and end time to midnight if event is allDay
    if (event.allDay) {

        event.oldStart = event.start;
        event.oldEnd = event.end;

        event.start.set('hours', 00);
        event.start.set('minutes', 00);
        event.end.set('hours', 00);
        event.end.set('minutes', 00);

    } else {

        event.start = event.oldStart;
        event.end = event.oldEnd;
    };

    updateEvent(event);
}
```

The updateEvent() function does an API call to update the event in the back-end, and when succesful the event is updated with

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: can you give us an example please with some real event data for an event where this problem occurs? Also what does "findEvent" do? Does it get the current event from fullCalendar itself (e.g. using the "clientEvents" method)? And have you watched your browser's network tools and/or set JS breakpoints to examine the values of the variables at the point the request is submitted to the server, to see what the start/end values are at that moment? i.e. to prove it's not the back-end's fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of your dates when stashing them.  You are calling `set` right after, and that wipes out your original times.

```
    event.oldStart = event.start.clone();
    event.oldEnd = event.end.clone();
```

When you switch back from allDay, your events have no duration.

Comment: Thank you! Creating a copy solved this issue for me :)